# NavigationStack has correct colors, but NavigationLink does not?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, toolbar, swiftui-navigationstack

I have this app that uses a `NavigationStack` to change the colors of the toolbar. When a navigation link is clicked, the navigation colors are not preserved onto the new screen and it goes back to default.

Here are 2 screenshot of what I mean:

This is what it looks like with the code below:

[image]

...and this is what it looks like when NavigationLink moves to the next page:

[image]

It isn't blue, and I want the back link to be white
I just want to point out that the n ext screen has no code to modify the style of the toolbar.

...and here is the code for it (I left all of the other views out so it is shorter. I had only included one view as a test):

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
        VStack{
            // Every other view goes here
            
            // Body views
            HStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: ScanScreen()){
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("LightGray"))
                        VStack{
                            Image("ScanQRImage")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .cornerRadius(20)
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 140, height: 2, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                            Text("Scan Code")
                                .bold()
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 5, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("SimpleQR")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbarBackground(Color("AccentColor"), for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

As you can see you are not assigning the values to the `NavigationStack`, but rather to the `VStack`. Those values are not relevant in some other context that you present after that, but you can assign those values again to that new context if you wish.

Also you may try to set those values to `WindowGroup`, that should affect all screens then.

Comment: How would I be able to do this? Would I add the same properties to the a new NavigationStack in the next screen?

Comment: Yes you need to assign the same values to your ScanScreen. 

You may try to set this to WindowGroup, that would probably stick to all screens.